# Survey tool to ask questions on individual pages - what are they called?

Tags: terminology, tools, surveys

Is there an off-the-shelf survey tool that can ask simple questions on specific pages? Along the lines of the "Was this information helpful?" on Microsoft's support pages ([example](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)). The user gets asked a simple question and if they click "yes", "no" (or whatever - needs to be configurable) then they get a pop-up where they can expand upon their answer.

I realise tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Exchange sites, so what are these on-page survey widgets generally called? I'd like to research the options and see what advice there is out there for making the most of them.

Comment: I can imagine that the term can vary in different contexts. Maybe you can add a few details like programming language or framework in the comments and leave the question on topic.

Comment: Thanks @jazZRo. The answers already given including the one I gave are just what I was looking for. Interesting that there is no standard name for this kind of survey. I like VWO's "on-page survey" term best. Seems most descriptive to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term you are looking for is *In-App Feedback Form*

[Doorbell.io](https://doorbell.io) is an example of that kind of feature.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard them called "**website intercept surveys**" ([source](https://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-blog/getting-online-feedback-for-websites-and-ads-with-website-intercept-surveys/)) or "(targeted) **website surveys**" ([source1](https://qualaroo.com/website-survey/), [source2](https://webengage.com/survey/)).

Examples include [Qualaroo](https://qualaroo.com/) and [WebEngage](https://webengage.com/survey/).

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a couple of further terms:

- On-page surveys ([VWO](https://vwo.com/on-page-surveys/))
- Feedback polls ([Hotjar](https://docs.hotjar.com/docs/what-is-hotjar#feedback-tools))